# check multiple guard controller

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un módulo que necesito que esté visible para 3 roles (web, docente y alumnos). En el controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:web,docente,alumnos');
}
```

y cuando llamo al Blade no se como unificar las 3 rutas, ya que con 2 si lo hago

```
<a href="{{route((Auth::guard('docente')->check())?'doc.documentos':web.documentos')}}">Documentos</a>
```

Hasta el momento lo tengo funcionando con los roles *web* y *docente*, pero no sé cómo agregarle el tercero.

Answer (score 0):

Sería demasiada lógica para la vista, podrías crear un helper (aunque no es lo más recomendado), facade o tener un servicio si es algo muy elaborado, pero dicha comprobación no debería estar en la vista.

Podría ser algo así muy básico en el controlador:

```
$role = Auth::guard('docente')->check()
        ? 'doc' 
        : (
            Auth::guard('web')->check()
            ? 'web'
            : 'alumnos'
        );
```

En la vista:

```
<a href="{{route($role.'documentos')}}">
```